# Can I use an Application developed with Flex Builder Trial?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, flexbuilder

Can I create an application with Flex Builder Trial ( that I have just downloaded ) and use that application on my website ?

But all of you that use Flex Builder have the licence ?? It's very expensive for me ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The builder does nothing to limit the swf files that are generated during the trial period. The trial is practically full version, just for a limited time.

If money is an issue you don't have to use flex builder. You can run eclipse with the flex plug-in and the flex SDK is free. I use the builder myself, but I'm sure Google can help you set up eclipse.

Comment: Note that Flex Builder has two modes - a graphical one, and a code editor (for editing MXML code). If you don't mind giving up the graphical part, you can write MXML in any old editor, and compile it into a flex app using the (free) SDK. What paying for Flex Builder gets you is the graphical editor.

Comment: That graphical editor is super sweet when your team includes a designer with no programming knowledge. Our designer can build the GUI complete with styles and all, then pass the project to us to code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you will not use charts it will be absolutely the same app as an app built with a licensed version of FB. You can even build an application without a Flex Builder at all by using free Flex SDK.